# javascript objects using the same overwritten variable

Tags: javascript, object, webgl

I have a javascript object that I am using. I have a verts array that i want to keep as is(The var called verts). Within the object i have a setScalar()method which will take this verts matrix and apply a scalar(jus a simple for loop multipling each value).When I create a new object I apply my scalar but when i create a new object i dont reference the original verts array it seems to apply the scalar to the scaled verts used in the object previous.

here is the verts array:

```
var verts = [
            // Front face
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

            // Back face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Top face
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

            // Bottom face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Right face
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Left face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
        ];
```

and here is how I set it in the object.

```
//Cube object
    function Cube(name, vertices, cubeVertInd, color, scale, positionX, positionY, positionZ) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.cubeVertexIndices = cubeVertInd;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
        this.positionZ = positionZ;
        this.setColor(color);
        this.setScale(vertices, scale);
    }
```

this is the setScale method

```
Cube.prototype.setScale = function(vertices, scale) 
    {
        var length = vertices.length;
        for( var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] *= scale; 
        }
    }
```

I know this is what happened because when i use this with webgl I get different sizes depending on what size i make the first object. If i set the object to scale 2 then set the next object to scale 0.1 even though the original verts is all 1's i get 0.2 as the second objects scale. this shows that the scale i set in the first object is being used rather than verts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clone your `vertices` array, because otherwise it's always a reference to the original `vert` array.

Try this:

```
//Cube object
    function Cube(name, vertices, cubeVertInd, color, scale, positionX, positionY, positionZ) 
    {
        // make a copy of the vertices
        vertices = vertices.slice();

        this.name = name;
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.cubeVertexIndices = cubeVertInd;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
        this.positionZ = positionZ;
        this.setColor(color);
        this.setScale(vertices, scale);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I have one more issue. See the `this.positionX` a similar thing happens when i set the positions is there anyway I can make these unique to each iteration of the object?

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `setScale()` for this purpose, you can use `Array.prototype.map()` method and remove the function `setScale()`.

In this case another new object is created, scaled and assigned to `this.vertices` .

```
function Cube(name, vertices, cubeVertInd, color, scale, positionX, positionY, positionZ) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.vertices = vertices.map(function(value){
                             return value*scale;
                        });
        this.cubeVertexIndices = cubeVertInd;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
        this.positionZ = positionZ;
        this.setColor(color);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answer to `a similar thing happens when i set the positions is there anyway I can make these unique to each iteration of the object?`

A generic solution to this problem is to have a clone function that can, well, return a clone of an object (not reference). So suppose if you have a base object with `{verts: [1,2,3..], positionX: 5, ...}` etc what you want to do when creating a new object is `newObj = clone(baseObj), then newObj.setScale(-1)`.

And one implementation of said clone function:

```
var clone = function(obj,visited){
    if (obj === null || typeof(obj) !== "object"){ // primitives and functions
        return obj;
    }
    visited = visited || [];

    if (visited.indexOf(obj)===-1){ // enable cloning objects with circular references at cost of linear search;
        visited.push(obj);
        if (obj instanceof RegExp){
            return new RegExp(obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Date){
            return new Date(obj);
        } else if (Array.isArray(obj)){ // the [[Class]] of arrays can only be set by using Array constructor or [];
            var newObj = [];
        } else if (obj.constructor !== undefined){
            newObj = Object.create(obj.constructor.prototype);
        } else {
            throw new TypeError("How to clone object: "+obj+" is undefined.", obj);
        }

    } else { // if object already seen/ circular reference; just return reference to it
        return obj;
    }

    for(var key in obj) { // recursive call itself;
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newObj[key] = clone(obj[key],visited);
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};
```